# Gravação muito lenta após adicionar Trigger em Inserção MYSQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

Quando eu insiro essa trigger no meu banco de dados está ocorrendo uma lentidão, chegando a dar essa mensagem:

**Errormessage: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction**

Minha trigger está conforme abaixo, o campo cod_prod da tabela produtos está indexado corretamente.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER ESTOQUEENTRADA 
BEFORE INSERT

  ON estoque FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

  UPDATE produtos SET quant_estoque = quant_estoque + NEW.quant_prod WHERE cod_prod = NEW.cod_prod;

END;//

DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui, as vezes te ajuda: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100506/why-update-trigger-makes-insertion-slow-in-mysql

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, porem verifiquei todos os itens citados na lista e o meu script não estava com nenhum dos problemas citados.

Comment: Já tentou fazer a _trigger_ no `after` ao invés de fazer no `before`?

Comment: tentei agora no after, a demora foi a mesma.

Comment: Notei que isso só acontece se a query está dentro de uma transação.